# Create whole page screen shot using QWebPage

Tags: qt, qwebpage

I am using Qt (the fancy browser example with the Qt creator) to create a screen shot of web pages using this code (taken and converted from [here](http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2008/12/03/create-screenshots-of-a-web-page-using-python-and-qtwebkit/)):

```
QImage *image = new QImage(view->page()->mainFrame()->contentsSize(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
QPainter *painter = new QPainter(image);

view->page()->mainFrame()->render(painter);

painter->end();
image->save(view->title() + "png");
```

But it only creates a screen shot of the visible portion of the page (view port).

If I add this line at the beginning, the screen shot is created from the whole page, but the problem is, it adds a new scroll bar each time a page loads.

```
view->page()->setViewportSize(view->page()->mainFrame()->contentsSize());
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to disable the scrollbars:

```
page()->mainFrame()->setScrollBarPolicy(Qt::Vertical, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
page()->mainFrame()->setScrollBarPolicy(Qt::Horizontal, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

For a complete example, use what I have described 3.5 years ago in [Capturing web pages](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/01/15/capturing-web-pages/) blog post. The code repository for that has been since moved to http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/graphics-dojo.

If you pay attention to the above example, there is no need to create QWebView. You can totally work only from QWebPage instance.

Comment: Both links are expired

Answer (score 4):

It looks like "wkhtmltopdf" (["wkhtmltopdf"](https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf)) has the correct implementation for this - search for "painter" in src/lib/imageconverter.cc.